# Center positioning text in hero div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-position

Whit this code, the text isnt positioned vertically center on the div.
I dont understand it, because i gived the positions 50%.
And for the image, cant i give a custom height, what i want?

On my  pic, the blue line on the top is the navbar, dont mind it.

```
<section class="bgimage-fooldal">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hero-text-fooldal">
        <h2 class="hero_title">Hello, world! Full width Hero-unit header</h2>
        <p class="hero_desc">This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique. Vevőidről, szállítóidról online információt nyerhetsz, így értesülhetsz arról.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-large hero_to_link">Árajánlat kérése »</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


/*************************** Hero css ****************************/
.bgimage-fooldal {
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background: url('../images/assets/teszt-1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.hero-text-fooldal {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give position:relative to bgimage-fooldal class so it will vertical center as per your div height

```css
.bgimage-fooldal {
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background: url('https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position:relative;
}
.hero-text-fooldal {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

```html
<section class="bgimage-fooldal">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hero-text-fooldal">
        <h2 class="hero_title">Hello, world! Full width Hero-unit header</h2>
        <p class="hero_desc">This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique. Vevőidről, szállítóidról online információt nyerhetsz, így értesülhetsz arról.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-large hero_to_link">Árajánlat kérése »</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flexbox to achieve this.  For example:

```
.hero-text-fooldal {
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background: url('../images/assets/teszt-1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Remove the styles from `.hero-text-fooldal`

Comment: Thank you, but the prewious post helped me, so i used positin:relative.